# Logically equivalent code producing different results

Tags: java

I have never encountered this sort of problem in Java before. All this code and the full project may be found at [my GitHub](https://github.com/kb100/SimpleGame). I have a `Snowflake` class with class hierarchy:

```
Snowflake extends SolidRectangle extends Movable extends Drawable extends Object
```

The following two code sections in my `Snowflake` class produce different graphical results in my game:

```
//In Snowflake class
public void decay()
{
    age++;
    color = randomSnowflakeColor();
    if(age == 5)
    {
        super.remove();
        Snowflake.Mempool.returnSnowflake(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
//In Snowflake class
public void decay()
{
    age++;
    color = randomSnowflakeColor();
    if(age == 5)
    {
        this.remove();
    }

public void remove()
{
    super.remove();
    Snowflake.Mempool.returnSnowflake(this);
}
```

Neither `SolidRectangle` nor `Movable` overrides the `remove` method, but `Drawable` does, with the following implementation:

```
//In Drawable class
public void remove()
{
    game.remove(this);
}
```

and `GameContent game` has the following implementation:

```
//In GameContent class
public synchronized void remove(Drawable drawable)
{
    removeQueue.add(drawable);
}
```

I will spare you the details of `removeQueue`, suffice it to say that it is exactly what you expect.

As for `Snowflake.Mempool`, I know manual memory management isn't usually part of a Java programmer's day, but I found there was too much overhead in creating and garbage collecting these snowflakes, so I thought I would just reuse old snowflakes to avoid this overhead. Please don't get distracted by this. My question is about how the two first code blocks could possibly be different, when they appear to be functionally equivalent.

So, how can the two first code block be producing different results?

Comment: Perhaps the different comes from something else that calls Snowflake.remove(), which has different behavior in these two cases?

Comment: Put log in each of you methods so that you can observe which method is being called in which order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the same result is expected when calling `decay()`, different behaviour of your class may result when `remove()` is called from *elsewhere* in the code.

Using your IDE, search for usages of the `remove()` method and all may be revealed.

Comment: Thank you for this! `remove` is called by the `CollisionHandler` which recognized it as a `SolidRectangle` and called it as `((SolidRectangle) snowflake).remove()` so it called the `Drawable` version instead of the `Snowflake` version of the code.

Comment: Actually this was not the problem... I added a cast and verified that the correct version is being called but I am still getting different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you said this:

> remove is called by the CollisionHandler which recognized it as a SolidRectangle and called it as ((SolidRectangle) snowflake).remove() so it called the Drawable version instead of the Snowflake version of the code.

I don't think this is a correct explanation.

You seem to be saying that this:

```
Snowflake snowflake = ...
((SolidRectangle) snowflake).remove();
```

would cause the overridden `SolidRectangle.remove()` method to be called on the snowflake.  That is incorrect.  Once the method has been overridden, it cannot be called on a `Snowflake` except by a `Snowflake` method (or `Snowflake` supertype method) calling `super.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that since `Snowflake.Mempool` acts as a stack, the most recently destroyed snowflakes are used to make the new snowflakes. I kept all the `Drawable` elements in an `ArrayList<Drawable>`. This combination caused certain snowflakes to appear twice in the `ArrayList<Drawable>` which consequently wrecked my frame adjusting algorithm. Switching to a `HashSet<Drawable>` resolved the issue.